# Can I use Future Perfect Continuous to describe actions that will be happening in the future for some period of time?

Tags: tense, future-tense, future-continuous

I've been reading about Future Continuous and Future Perfect Continuous tenses in an article (I'm not providing a link, because it's in Russian).

It says that I should use Future Continuos with following marker words:

- This time next week/month/year
  **This time next week I will be having dinner with Tiffany**
- The whole morning/evening/day
  **Tom will be waiting for you the whole day**
- During the [part of the day]
  **We will be playing Twister during the evening**
- From ... till
  **They won’t be working from 9 p.m. till 11 p.m**
- For ... hours
  **I will be fixing the bugs for 3 hours**
- All day long
  **I bet she will be sleeping all day long**

  **My question** is can I use Future Perfect Continuous for all of this cases instead of Future Continuous? As I've understood, Future Perfect Continuos is used for actions that will be happening in the future for some period of time. So I guess it's gonna be correct if I'd use Future Perfect Continuous in this case, or isn't?

Comment: The future perfect continuous wouldn't work in all those cases. It is used for actions that, at a particular time in the future, will _have been_ happening for some time. So, if you are travelling to Paris five days from now, you could say "This time next week I will have been in Paris for two days." "By five o'clock I will have been fixing the bugs for three hours."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, насколько тактично писать на русском ответ на англоязычном сервисе, но sorry for my Russian answer everybody - I just try to explain this guy the thing in his native language (Hope your native language is really Russian...)

Как я понял из того, что перелопатил в Интернете - Future Perfect Continuous используется для описания 2 действий:

- Действие, которое начнется в будущем (или уже началось к настоящему моменту) и будет продолжаться (находиться в процессе) вплоть до **определенного** момента в будущем. В этот самый момент действие может либо остановиться находиться в процессе, либо продолжить находиться в процессе дальше.
- Действие, которое начнется в будущем (или уже началось к настоящему моменту) и будет продолжаться (находиться в процессе) и результат которого будет очевиден (важен) в какой-то **определенный** момент будущего. При этом неважно, будет все еще находиться в процессе действие в этот самый момент или уже нет, и если даже нет, неважно, насколько давно оно закончило находиться в процессе относительно этого самого момента. Важно только то, что сам факт того, что действие находилось в процессе в течение какого-то времени, будет важен для нас на тот момент – результат этого процесса будет очевиден.

При этом этот **определенный момент** в будущем может либо задаваться явно, либо быть понятным из контекста.
Если задается **явно**, он может быть задан либо конкретной временной точкой:

```
By next year
By then и т.д
```

либо **другим действием в будущем**, которое выражено через adverbial clause of time (при этом в этом adverbial clause используется Present Simple):

```
How long will you have been studying when you graduate?
```

Понимаю, что все вышенаписанное может звучать тоже довольно нечетко, но исходя из вышенаписанного, основное различие между Future Continuous и Future Perfect Continuous в следующем: Future Continuous используется для того, чтобы акцентировать внимание на том, что действие **находится в процессе (выполняется) в определенный момент в будущем**, а Future Perfect Continuous акцентирует внимание на том, что **к определенному моменту в будущем действие уже находилось в процессе (выполнялось) какое-то время.**

Во всех же примерах, которые вы привели, акцент по смыслу делается именно на то, что действие находится в процессе в какой-то определенный момент (а значит, должен быть использован именно Future Continuous) - например, в первом вашем примере говорится:" **через неделю в это же самое время я буду находиться в процессе поедания ужина с Томом**". Во втором примере говорится: "Том **будет находиться в процессе ожидания тебя весь день**".

Future Perfect Continuous мог бы быть использован для того, чтобы сказать, например:

This time tomorrow I will have been waiting for you 48 hours already.

Что будет означать: в это время завтра я **уже как 48 часов** буду находиться в процессе ожидания тебя. То есть акцент именно на том, что к определенному моменту в будущем (это же время завтрашнего дня) ты будешь находиться в процессе уже какое-то время (48 часов).
Надеюсь, написанное хоть как-то поможет разобраться в вопросе и мой самый первый ответ тут(!) не снесут =)

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help OP by writing a detailed answer in their supposed native language. But the Stack Exchange model is built on the premise that all the Q&As are not only for the benefit of the askers but also the entire community and future visitors. An answer in a language other than English, especially on an English learning focused site, is very limiting in its reach and potentially confusing and unhelpful to most community members. Personally I don't mind it at all, but there's a good chance your answer will be flagged by others and picked up by Smoke Detector.

Comment: I would recommend, when you have the time, supplementing your answer with English explanations, just so the community will be able to read your answer, benefit from it, and vote on it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) (Yes, I am Russian indeed). I guess I've figured it out now